# What is the rule of converting subscript of awk array?

Tags: linux, unix, awk, gawk

I know, the subscript of `awk` array must be a string.

```
[root@localhost]# awk 'END {array[A0]="empty"; print array[""]}'
empty
```

So in above command line, because `A0` is not quoted as `"A0"` , it stands for a variable. Because the variable `A0` hasn't been set value before, the value is `""`. So the `print array[""]` outputs `empty`.

But in the following command:

```
[root@localhost]#  awk 'END {array[0]="empty"; print array[""], array["0"]}'
 empty
```

The value of `array[""]` is `NULL` while `array["0"]` is `"empty"`. Per my understanding, that's because the variable can't begin with digit, `array[0]` is converted to `array["0"]` by default. Is it right? What is the rule of converting subscript of `awk` array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Array subscripts in awk are strings, so when you use an expression as array subscript, it is converted to a string (if it isn't one already). `0` is a number, not a variable, so the following applies (from [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html)):

> A numeric value that is exactly equal to the value of an integer (see Concepts Derived from the ISO C Standard) shall be converted to a string by the equivalent of a call to the **sprintf** function (see String Functions) with the string `"%d"` as the *fmt* argument and the numeric value being converted as the first and only *expr* argument. Any other numeric value shall be converted to a string by the equivalent of a call to the **sprintf** function with the value of the variable **CONVFMT** as the *fmt* argument and the numeric value being converted as the first and only *expr* argument. The result of the conversion is unspecified if the value of **CONVFMT** is not a floating-point format specification.

`0` is an integer, so it gives `"0"` when converted to string, not `""`. This is because in C code, after `sprintf(buf, "%d", 0)`, `buf` would contain the string `"0"`.

As for variable names: in the [awk grammar](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/awk.html#tag_04_06_13_16), variables are described by the token **NAME**. The lexicographical convention for it are as follows:

> 9) A sequence of underscores, digits, and alphabetics from the portable character set (see the Base Definitions volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001, Section 6.1, Portable Character Set), beginning with an underscore or alphabetic, shall be considered a word.
>
> 12) The token **NAME** shall consist of a word that is not a keyword or a name of a built-in function and is not followed immediately (without any delimiters) by the '(' character.

Tokens that follow this description are variables, initially empty, and when an empty variable is converted to string, it yields the empty string.

To wit:

- `0` is a number
- `a` is a variable name
- `_` is a variable name
- `a0` is a variable name
- `_0` is a variable name
- `0a` is parsed as `0 a` (the concatenation of `0` and the variable `a`)

Comment: 0a is not a syntax error, it evaluates to just 0a when used as a subscript. Try `awk '{a="c";b[0a]}END{for (i in b)print i}' file` and you will see it prints `0c`

Comment: Oh, interesting, and rather unexpected. Do you know whether that is required by POSIX or gawk/mawk-specific?

Comment: Funky. As far as I can see, it is required by POSIX, and the lexical convention "An integer constant cannot begin with 0x or include the hexadecimal digits 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', or 'F'." leads me to believe that this is intentional. This means that given the code `{ xf="foo"; print 0xf }`, gawk's behavior of printing `15` is non-standard while mawk is compliant by printing `0foo`.

Comment: Yes, allowing the use of hex (and octal) constants (e.g. `0xf`) in your script is a gawk extension, see http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Nondecimal_002dnumbers, and can be disabled with the `--posix` flag in the unlikely event that the resultant behavior is undesirable. Note that means that `a[021]; for (i in a) print i` in gawk will print `17`.

Comment: @EdMorton, does that mean `--non-decimal-data` is defined by default? Or does option that mean something different than what we are talking about?

Comment: @jas no. That flag is for processing non-decimal values in the input, not using them hard-coded in the script. I assume the logic is that if you use a hex number in your script then you wrote it and so you DO want it treated as such, but if an input file contains text that looks like hex values you can't just assume that's what they are and diverge from the historical/POSIX treatment of them by default.